# remove selected image Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

i want to be able to delete only selected images from a container these images are selected from a library in the page. the user can select as many images as he or she likes the images are then shown in a container but i cant seem to find a way to delete them i can only hide the image i want to be able to delete the image and prevent it from hiding. i apologize for  not having a fiddle my code is very long. here is a script

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/></div>');
    $('.imgdrag').draggable();
    $('#fotos').droppable();
    $('.modal-content').resizable();


    $(".download").attr("href", $(this).attr('src'));
    $(".download").show();
  });



});
```

```html
<div id="fotos" class="bananas"><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) the selected element if that is what you want.